# How temporarily stop collision check

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, collision

Ive looked around and couldn't find a simple method. I have an animation that plays when a collision occurs, although the animation can't get past the first frame until the objects are completely separated as the collision detection keeps firing.

Does anyone know how to either force the animation to play all the way through or have the collision detection only check once? (although the collision detection would need to be running again afterwards to repeat the process).

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Heli.frame, AstroidBig.frame)) {
        animation2.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image 1"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image 2"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image 3"],
                                     nil];
        [animation2 setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
        animation2.animationDuration = 0.4;
        [animation2 startAnimating];
        [self performSelector:@selector(enemyreset) withObject:nil afterDelay:1]; 
}
```

The 'enemyreset' is the function that will reset the object back into play from the collision point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a flag in the above method to indicate that you are animating (you will need to add it as a property).  Only start the animation if you are not already animating.  Then reset the flag in your `enemyreset` method.

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Heli.frame, AstroidBig.frame)) {
    if (!self.alreadyAnimating) {
        animation2.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image 1"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image 2"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image 3"],
                                     nil];
        [animation2 setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
        animation2.animationDuration = 0.4;
        [animation2 startAnimating];
        [self performSelector:@selector(enemyreset) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
        self.alreadyAnimating = YES; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to explain a little more @pbasdf ? 

In the end I couldn't get it to work. Would be because of my limited coding understanding.

Comment: Sure, if you can add a little more detail about your problem.  In particular, which method is the above code in?  How are the Heli.frame and AsteroidBig.frame updated?